# Como posso mostrar os próximos 7 Dias (Agenda) C#

Tags: c#, array, string, datetime

Viva, boa noite

Estou a trabalhar numa solução C#, em que tenho de desenvolver uma agenda e pretendo a certa altura do programa mostrar os eventos (Se existirem) bem como mostrar os seguintes 7 dias, mesmo que estes não tenham enventos marcados.

Eu desenvolvi um metodo, que dada uma determinada data `(int dia, int mes, int ano)` me devolve na verdade todos os dias do mês indicado mas na verdade eu preciso de algo que me devolva por exemplo:

Se estivermos a 1 de algum mes - O programa deve devolver desde o dia 1 até ao dia 7

Se estivermos por exemplo a 10 - O programa deve devolver de 10 a 17

Portanto sempre uma sequência de 7 Dias. Eis o método que tenho de momento:

```
        public string ShowWeekendEvents(int Day, int Month, int Year)
        {


            string aux = "";
            for (int i=0; i<totalEventos; i++)
            {
                if(ev[i].DayMonthYear.Day>=Day&&ev[i].DayMonthYear.Month==Month&&ev[i].DayMonthYear.Year==Year)
                {
                        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}-{2} {3}-{4} ", ev[i].DayMonthYear.Day, ev[i].DayMonthYear.Month, ev[i].DayMonthYear.Year, ev[i].HoraInicial, ev[i].MinInicial);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        aux = "Evento: " + ev[i].Events.ToString() + "\n";
                        Console.WriteLine("Data de inicio: {0}/{1}/{2}", ev[i].DayMonthYear.Day, ev[i].DayMonthYear.Month, ev[i].DayMonthYear.Year);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Data Final: {0}/{1}/{2}", ev[i].FinalDayMonthYear.Day, ev[i].FinalDayMonthYear.Month, ev[i].FinalDayMonthYear.Year);
                        aux += "Hora Inicio:" + ev[i].HoraInicial.ToString() + "h " + ev[i].MinInicial.ToString() + "Min" + "\n";
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        aux += "Hora Final:" + ev[i].HoraFinal.ToString() + "h " + ev[i].MinFinal.ToString() + "Min   \n";
                        Console.WriteLine(aux);
                        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------");




                        if (ev[i].DayMonthYear.Day >= Day)
                            if (ev[i].DayMonthYear.Day > 7)
                                break;
                            else if (Day == 8 && ev[i].DayMonthYear.Day > 13)
                                break;
                   }
                    //during 7 days


                }
                /*    
                else if (ev[i].DayMonthYear.Day != Day && ev[i].DayMonthYear.Month == Month && ev[i].DayMonthYear.Year == Year)
                {

                    while (j < week-1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}-{2} {3}-{4} ", ev[i].DayMonthYear.Day, ev[i].DayMonthYear.Month, ev[i].DayMonthYear.Year, ev[i].HoraInicial, ev[i].MinInicial);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        aux = "Evento: " + ev[i].Events.ToString() + "\n";
                        Console.WriteLine("Data de inicio: {0}/{1}/{2}", ev[i].DayMonthYear.Day, ev[i].DayMonthYear.Month, ev[i].DayMonthYear.Year);
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Data Final: {0}/{1}/{2}", ev[i].FinalDayMonthYear.Day, ev[i].FinalDayMonthYear.Month, ev[i].FinalDayMonthYear.Year);
                        aux += "Hora Inicio:" + ev[i].HoraInicial.ToString() + "h " + ev[i].MinInicial.ToString() + "Min" + "\n";
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        aux += "Hora Final:" + ev[i].HoraFinal.ToString() + "h " + ev[i].MinFinal.ToString() + "Min   \n";
                        Console.WriteLine(aux);
                        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");



                    }
                }
                 * */

        return aux;
}
```

No entanto estou bastante confuso e não estou a conseguir que o programa passe para o utilizador o que na verdade é pretendido. Será que me podem ajudar a reformular o código?

Desde já obrigado.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Crie uma classe estática**

```
static class Intervalo
{
    public static IEnumerable<DateTime> IntervaloDias(this DateTime data, int dias)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, (data.AddDays(dias) - data).Days).Select(d => data.AddDays(d));
    }
}
```

**Para pegar o intervalo de 7 dias**

```
var intervalo = new DateTime(2015, 1, 31).IntervaloDias(7);
foreach (var datas in intervalo)
{
    Console.WriteLine(datas);
}
Console.ReadKey();
//intervalo.ToList() retorna como uma lista de datas
```

> **Resultado:**

[image: Resultado]

**Use a imaginação, boa sorte.** @vitor-ferreira

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738748/create-an-array-or-list-of-all-dates-between-two-dates